# Making a Swing Logo Quiz

Tags: java, arrays, swing

So first off, I'm a novice programmer, so I don't have the best knowledge of code and I don't really know how to use stackoverflow very well either.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Logoquiz extends JPanel
{
   private JPanel box;
   private JPanel sprite;
   private JPanel subtitle; 
   private JPanel opt;  
   private JButton rBOX;
   private JButton q;  
   private JButton sub;
   private JButton oA;
   private JButton oB;
   private int qNum;
   private int []numbers;
   private String []names;
   private int currentN;
   private int mysteryN;

   public Character()
   {

      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("logos.txt"));
      int []numbers = new int[9];
      String []names = new String[9];
      for(int w = 0; w < 9; w++)
      {
         numbers[w]=inFile.nextInt();
         names[w]=inFile.next();
      }  

      currentN=pickNum();
      mysteryN=pickNum();

      setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

      box = new JPanel();
      box.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
      box.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,490));

      rBOX = new JButton("Click Next to Begin!");
      rBOX.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1170,480));
      Color bg = new Color(25,179,230);
      rBOX.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
      rBOX.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
      rBOX.setForeground(Color.BLACK);  
      box.add(rBOX);

      add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      box.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    //----------------------------------------------------------

      subtitle = new JPanel();
      subtitle.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
      subtitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,170));

      q = new JButton(statement());
      q.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1170,80));
      q.setBackground(bg);
      q.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
      q.setForeground(Color.white);
      q.addActionListener(new qListener());
      subtitle.add(q);

      sub = new JButton("NEXT");
      sub.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1170,80));
      sub.setBackground(bg);
      sub.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
      sub.setForeground(Color.white);
      sub.addActionListener(new subListener());
      subtitle.add(sub);     

      add(subtitle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      subtitle.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    //----------------------------------------------------------

      opt = new JPanel();
      opt.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
      opt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200,100));

      oA = new JButton("True");
      oA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580,90));
      oA.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
      oA.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
      oA.setForeground(Color.white);
      opt.add(oA);

      oB = new JButton("False");
      oB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580,90));
      oB.setBackground(Color.RED);
      oB.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
      oB.setForeground(Color.white);
      opt.add(oB);

      add(opt, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      opt.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

 }
      //---------------------------------------------------------

   private class subListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
      {
         rBOX.setText("");
         rBOX.setIcon(new ImageIcon(numbers[currentN]+".jpg"));
         currentN=pickNum();
      }

   }

   private class qListener implements ActionListener
   {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click)
      {
         rBOX.setText("");
         rBOX.setIcon(new ImageIcon(numbers[currentN]+".jpg"));
      }

   }

      //---------------------------------------------------------

   public int pickNum()
   {

      qNum = (int)(Math.random()*9+1);
      return qNum;

   }

   public String statement()
   {

      return "This is the logo of"+names[mysteryN]+" .";

   }



}
```

Now I'm getting this compile error,

```
Character.java:28: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
      Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("logos.txt"));
                       ^
1 error
```

I'm not sure what it even means.

So I've made all the changes everyone has suggested and it compiles! 
However, when I ran it I got this;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Logoquiz.<init>(Logoquiz.java:31)
    at TERA.main(TERA.java:17)
```

TERA is the driver by the way.

Comment: So what does it do now, what do you want it to do?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html. Also, it is best not to remove parts of your question after they've been answered. Leave it intact so that other people having the same problem or getting the same errors can find this and get use from it.

Comment: `"So I've made all the changes everyone has suggested and it compiles! However, when I ran it I got this;"` -- that's a new and unrelated problem, and so deserves a new and unrelated question. What you need to do is to ask your small program, but for it, write a small non-GUI program that does nothing but extract the text you're trying to extract into your arrays, and then print out the results. Then post the small program, the small data file, and the error messages that you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop is written wrong, and will never end:

```
for(int w = 1; 1 <= 9; w++)
```

The condition `1 <= 9` will always be true, and so the loop will never end.

Instead do:

```
for(int w = 0; w < 9; w++)
```

Note that arrays are 0 based. If your w variable goes to 9, you will run out of array space and get an array index out of bounds exception.

Even better is to avoid magic numbers:

```
for (int w = 0; w < numbers.length; w++)
```

---

Regarding:

> By resource class I mean it's not a driver, so it doesn't contain a main method and this class Character is a JPanel being called by another class that contains the main method and JFrame.

Then have your constructor throw the exception, and let the other class handle the exception by calling the constructor inside of a try and catch block.

---

As a side recommendation, I'd change the name of this class since it clashes with a name of a core Java class.

---

Another problem is that your code is shadowing some of its variables, namely names and numbers. By re-declaring the variables in the constructor, you're leaving the class fields null. The solution is to not re-declare the variables.

i.e., change this:

```
public Character() throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("logos.txt"));
  int[] numbers = new int[9];
  String[] names = new String[9];
```

to this:

```
public Character() throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("logos.txt"));
  numbers = new int[9];
  names = new String[9];
```

---

Next we'll need to work on layout manager usage....

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception. Needs to handle it.

Comment: @Braj: I thought that I addressed that error. If the constructor throws the exception, that's all that this bit of code needs to do.

Comment: +1 for addressing array index out of bounds exception as well.